# Simple Undefined Method Error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, each, instance-variables, enumerable

I'm probably overlooking something simple here but I still haven't been able to find the problem.

Controller:
(First line is a long Thinking Sphinx query)

```
@artwork_q = Artwork.search params[:q], :conditions => {:subject => params[:artwork][:subject_ids], :location => params[:artwork][:location_ids], :artist_last => params[:artwork][:artist_id], :artist_first => params[:artwork][:artist_id]}, :order => params[:sort][:title]
@last_artwork = Artwork.new
@last_artwork = @artwork_q.last
render 'index2'
```

View:

```
<% @artwork_q.each.with_index do |art, index| %>
    <div class="a-result<%= " last-one" if art.id == @last_artwork.id %>" id="<%= index %>">
<% end %>
```

I tested `art.id` and that's working fine. It's the `@last_artwork.id` that's raising the error which is this:

```
NoMethodError in Artworks#index2
Showing /Users/<user>/Developer/<project>/<rails_root>/app/views/artworks/index2.html.erb where line #49 raised:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[].last => nil` i.e. your query returns no results.  Simply check `@artwork_q` has some results in before looping through them.

```
<% unless @artwork_q.blank? %>
  <% @artwork_q.each.with_index do |art, index| %>
    <div class="a-result<%= " last-one" if art.id == @last_artwork.id %>" id="<%= index %>">
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it was actually something else I just found but I didn't take this into account either so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% unless @artwork_q.blank? %>
  <% @artwork_q.each.with_index do |art, index| %>
    <% unless @last_artwork.blank? %>
      <div class="a-result<%= " last-one" if art.id == @last_artwork.id %>" id="<%= index %>">
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```